# Column values based on multiple conditions being true in different columns

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new value in df_test based on if a row has been found in a second dataframe with 3 conditions being true.
The conditions are as follows:

1. The names must be equal in both tables (df_test$name = df_prod$name)
2. The df_prod$birthdate must be at least 2020-01-01 (the persons birthdate can not be earlier than 2020-01-01)
3. The df_test$import_date must be smaller than the df_prod$sent_date

I think of it as a Vlookup with multiple conditions.

This is what I have so far:

```
df_test$V5 = case_when(df_test$name %in% df_prod$name &
                         df_test$import_date < df_prod$sent_date &
                         df_prod$birthday > as.Date('2020-01-01') & ~ 1,
                                        TRUE ~ 0)
```

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Comment: Does the two dataset have the same number of rows

Comment: No they dont, they also have a different amount of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a case of join i.e assuming that we don't have duplicates for 'name' in the 'df_prod', do a `left_join` from 'df_test' with the `select`ed columns in 'df_prod', and create the 'V5' by converting the compound logical expression to binary (`as.integer`)

```
library(dplyr)
df_test2 <- left_join(df_test, df_prod %>% 
            select(name, send_date, birthday), by = 'name') %>%
     mutate(V5 = as.integer(import_date < sent_date &
               birthday > as.Date('2020-01-01'))) %>%
     select(-send_date, birthday)
```

---

or we can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_test)[df_prod, V5 := as.integer(import_date < sent_date & 
           birthday > as.Date('2020-01-01')), on = .(name)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The only problem is that there are duplicates in the df_prod$name column and now it is multiplying the results. is there anyway I can surpass this issue?

Comment: @Gabriela if both of them have duplicates, there is a question of which value element it should match to.  Do you think you can use the `distinct` rows based on the `name` i.e. `left_join(df_test, df_prod %>% 
            select(name, send_date, birthday) %>% distinct(name, .keep_all = TRUE), by = 'name')`